# String concatenation with ( document.getElementById().value)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

```
onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'CatagoryName', document.getElementById('FirstName').value);"
```

I want to concatenate a string(for example 'User name') to the `document.getElementById('FirstName').value` parameter so that tracking the FirstName input from the user can be identified as User name.

Comment: Did you try to search how to concatenate two strings in javascript? Shouldn't be hard to find on the big world wide web or on stack..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work `'User name = ' + document.getElementById('FirstName').value`.

```
onclick="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker, 'CatagoryName', ('User name = ' + document.getElementById('FirstName').value) );"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').value += 'Your string to concat';
```